# Uniqueness of Predictable Quadratic Covariation

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, quadratic-variation

In order to prove that $\langle M,N \rangle$ is the only process which is continuous and has bounded variation such that 
\begin{align}
M_tN_t - \langle M,N \rangle_t
\end{align}
is a continuous martingale, I try to apply the Doob-Meyer decomposition on the right hand side of the useful equation
\begin{align}
M_tN_t = \frac{1}{2}\bigg( (M_t+N_t)^2 - M_t^2 - N_t^2 \bigg).
\end{align}

So, Doob-Meyer are stating that for $(X_t)$, a cadlag submartingale with $X_0=0$, $\exists!$ predictable process $(A_t)_t$ such that $A_0=0$ and
\begin{align}
\text{$M_t = X_t - A_t\ \ $ is a uniformly integrable process,}
\end{align}
i.e. $(X_t - A_t)_t$ is a martingale.

However, for me it is not yet clear how to complete the proof. Can somebody help me?

Comment: what are the assumptions over M and N ?

Comment: Nothing specific.

Comment: then you will allow me not answer in any specific way to your question

Comment: Well, nothing specific is given about the martingales. I think we could at least assume that $M$ and $N$ are $L^2$ martingales.